# COUNT(*) with LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY to include NULL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I'm trying to get the results from a table including the appearance count in a foreign table. This table can have 0 or more appearances.

like in the following example:

table: color

```
+------+---------+
|  id  |   name  |
+------+---------+
|  1   |   red   |
|  2   |   blue  |
|  3   |  yellow |
|  4   |  green  |
+------+---------+
```

table: fruit

```
+--------+----------+
|  name  | color_id |
+--------+----------+
| apple  |    1     |
| banana |    3     |
| grape  |    4     |
| lemon  |    3     |
+--------+----------+
```

So I need to list every color and the occurrence in the fruit table, returning something like this:

```
1, red, 1
2, blue, 0
3, yellow, 2
4, green, 1
```

I'm trying with this query:

```
SELECT `c`.`id`, `c`.`name`, COUNT(1)
FROM color `c`
LEFT JOIN fruit `f`
ON `c`.`id` = `f`.`color_id`
GROUP BY `c`.`id`
```

This query is returning a count of **1** for "blue" instead of **0**. beacuse the color "blue" doesn't appear in the fruit table

Comment: doesn't COUNT(1) always return 1?

Comment: Well, you are counting the number of 1's, and mysql does that. Replace `count(1)` with `count(f.name)`, then it will count the number of fruits.

Comment: @Jerry No, `COUNT(anything)` counts the number of non-null values encountered.

Comment: and there is exactly one non-null value in `count(1)` - the number 1. You can test that with the simple query `SELECT COUNT(1)`; `SELECT COUNT(2)` also returns 1, because there is still just the one scalar value in the `COUNT` expression.

Comment: no, COUNT(*) is the same as COUNT(1): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1

Comment: @Jerry, yes, no matter what you count with a bare(FROM-less) SELECT (other than a NULL literal, or null-valued variable), the result will always be 1. If you `SELECT COUNT([any non-null constant or unchanging variable]) FROM [an N rowed table]` you will get N. If you `SELECT COUNT(fieldX) FROM tableY` and half of the rows in tableY have a null value for fieldX, you will get a number equal to half the rows in tableY. `COUNT(1)` being equal to 1 has nothing to do with a scalar value in a count expression; `COUNT(DISTINCT [non-null constant...])` will always be one though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This works:

```
SELECT c.id, COUNT(f.name)
FROM color c
LEFT JOIN fruit f ON c.id = f.color_id
GROUP BY c.id
```

You have to count a field of fruit, so that NULL can be returned, which becomes a zero.

Answer (score 3):

You put count(1), change count(f.color_id)

```
select  
    c.id
    , c.name
    , count(f.color_id) as [Color Count]
from color as c
    left join fruit as f
    on c.id = f.color_id
group by c.id, c.name
```