# MYSQL returning the count of how many people logged an event

Tags: mysql, sql

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PommS.jpg

The above image shows my first table called events.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSBKX.jpg

This above table is linked to the events table and is used to check if a user logs an event. I want to obtain a count of how much each event was logged while displaying the event details. The problem I've encountered is that if an event has 0 logs it will not appear in the output.

This is the sql ive used:

```
SELECT event.`eventid`,
       event.`name`,
       `eventtime`,
       `location`,
       `datecreated`,
       `dateofevent`,
       `categoryname`,
       `description`,
       Count(participantlogs.eventid)
FROM   event,
       recreationalcategory,
       participantlogs
WHERE  recreationalcategory.categoryid = event.categoryid
       AND participantlogs.eventid = event.eventid
GROUP  BY event.eventid
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No images please; use formatted text for posting your sample data and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying rows with count 0 with mysql group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743456/displaying-rows-with-count-0-with-mysql-group-by)

Comment: A `LEFT JOIN` is probably what you're looking for. This way it will include the events that have 0 logs. Check out this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40918613/count-with-left-join-and-group-by-to-include-null-in-mysql).

Comment: Please don't use Old comma based Implicit joins and use Modern [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654278/2469308)

Comment: Invalid GROUP BY... You typically GROUP BY all the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation, and use `JOIN` keyword instead, relocate the join predicates to the `ON` clause. The `JOIN` keyword can be modified to with `LEFT` or `RIGHT` keyword to allow an *outer* join.

An *outer* join will return rows that don't have a match; exactly the use case described.

```
SELECT e.eventid
     , e.name
     , COUNT(p.eventid)
  FROM event e
  LEFT
  JOIN recreationalcategory c
    ON c.categoryid = e.categoryid
  LEFT
  JOIN participantlogs p
    ON p.eventid = e.eventid
 GROUP
    BY e.eventid
     , e.name
```

---

Another alternative would be to use a correlated subquery in the SELECT list rather than a join.  Assuming `eventid` is PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY in `event` table, we can eliminate the `GROUP BY` clause...

```
SELECT e.eventid
     , e.name
     , ( SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM participantlogs p
          WHERE p.eventid = e.eventid
       ) AS cnt
  FROM event e
  LEFT
  JOIN recreationalcategory c
    ON c.categoryid = e.categoryid
```

Answer (score 0):

A left join should do your job.

```
SELECT event.`eventid`,
       event.`name`,
       `eventtime`,
       `location`,
       `datecreated`,
       `dateofevent`,
       `categoryname`,
       `description`,
       Count(participantlogs.eventid)
FROM   event,
       recreationalcategory,
       participantlogs
WHERE  (recreationalcategory.categoryid = event.categoryid OR recreationalcategory.categoryid  is null)
       AND participantlogs.eventid = event.eventid
GROUP  BY event.eventid
```

on simply use `left join`

```
SELECT event.`eventid`,
           event.`name`,
           `eventtime`,
           `location`,
           `datecreated`,
           `dateofevent`,
           `categoryname`,
           `description`,
           Count(participantlogs.eventid)
     FROM   event 
     left join recreationalcategory 
       on recreationalcategory.categoryid = event.categoryid
     join participantlo on
       on participantlogs.eventid = event.eventid
    GROUP  BY event.eventid
```

Comment: invalid GROUP BY which can cause invalid results on MySQL without sql mode only_full_group_by.